# Select tags in parent class javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, anchor

I can use this to select all the anchor tags in a document, which works great...

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Specifically for replacing "href" functionality with "onclick" (for extending functionality from no javascript, adding thumbnails etc)

Except how can I get it to select just the anchor elements in a certain class of parent element (e.g. `pics`), leaving the bulk of anchors alone?

```
<a href="img/TEST/pretty.jpg">ignore me</a>
<div class="pics">
 <a href="img/TEST/testPic1.jpg">1 stuff....</a>
 <a href="img/TEST/testPic2.jpg">2 stuff...</a>
 <a href="img/TEST/TestPic3.jpg">3 stuff..</a>
 ...
 <a href="img/TEST/TestPicN.jpg">n stuff..</a>
</div>
```

...*without* additional libraries such as jQuery please!

Here's a quick demo...

```js
function go() {
    var anchorElements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i in anchorElements)
        anchorElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
a{background-color:#0F0;}
```

```html
<a href="img/TEST/pretty.jpg">ignore me</a>
<div class="pics">
 <a href="img/TEST/testPic1.jpg">1 stuff....</a>
 <a href="img/TEST/testPic2.jpg">2 stuff...</a>
 <a href="img/TEST/TestPic3.jpg">3 stuff..</a>
 ...
 <a href="img/TEST/TestPicN.jpg">n stuff..</a>
</div>
<button onclick="go()">Go!</button>
```

<sup>I know a workaround is just to select by a class applied to the elements that need modifying</sup>

Comment: you can do it with DOM selector easily

Comment: Not all A elements are links, you can get all the links using `document.links`. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll('.pics a')` to select a collection of `<a>` under `.pic` class

```js
function go() {
    var anchorElements = document.querySelectorAll('.pics a');
    for (var i in anchorElements)
        anchorElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
a{background-color:#0F0;}
```

```html
<a href="img/TEST/pretty.jpg">ignore me</a>
<div class="pics">
 <a href="img/TEST/testPic1.jpg">1 stuff....</a>
 <a href="img/TEST/testPic2.jpg">2 stuff...</a>
 <a href="img/TEST/TestPic3.jpg">3 stuff..</a>
 ...
 <a href="img/TEST/TestPicN.jpg">n stuff..</a>
</div>
<button onclick="go()">Go!</button>
```

Comment: Your answer will be much more useful for others if you explain what you changed and why. Please [edit] your answer.

Comment: Enough for my level xD, thanks! Looks like it uses CSS Selectors

Comment: It may be much more efficient to add a CSS rule rather than selecting then looping over all the relevant elements one at a time.